# No me permite hacer pod init mediante CocoaPods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Tengo un problema con el Cocoapods.

He actualizado el sistema operativo y migré a swift 5, pero desde entonces he tenido problemas con el cocoaPods. No se como solucionarlo

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/pod init Smiledu_app.xcodeproj
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.5.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-darwin15]
    RubyGems : 2.6.8
        Host : Mac OS X 10.14.4 (18E226)
       Xcode : 10.2 (10E125)
         Git : git version 2.6.2
Ruby lib dir : /Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ fc9b6a8380cb5551e20db3769a95ef039376836f
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-check           : 1.0.0
cocoapods-deintegrate     : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins         : 1.0.0
cocoapods-plugins-install : 0.0.1
cocoapods-search          : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats           : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk           : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try             : 1.1.0
```

#### Error

```
RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.8/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:218:in `initialize_from_file'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.8/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:103:in `open'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D+Unknown+object+version.&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6992 [closed] [16 comments]
   31 Jan 2019

- - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Malformed version number string ) during validation.
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8240 [closed] [17 comments]
    3 weeks ago
- Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>[], "outputFileListPaths"=>[]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7835 [closed] [47 comments]
  5 weeks ago

and 44 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D%20Unknown%20object%20version.&type=Issues&utf8=✓

Answer (score 1):

Por lo visto tienes cocoapods instalado desde un DMG y se daño al momento que actualizaste, lo que te recomiendo es que desinstales tu version de cocoapods, una vez desinstalado, abre una terminal y ejecuta el siguiente comando...

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Puede tardar un poco, pero despues de que termine ya deberias de poder hacer el

`pod init`

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.